# Update statement shows error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `CLAIMS`.

With its original columns, I can update the relevant columns with data with no issues

```
UPDATE CLAIMS
SET LAST_UPDATED_DT = GETDATE()
WHERE ID = 'id' (whichever id is specified)
```

After I altered the table to include 2 new columns, the `UPDATE` statement no longer works and is throwing an error

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Note: the columns are new and does not have overlapping names with any of the other columns:

```
DRAWING_FROM varchar(50)
VENUE_TYPE varchar(50)
```

I honestly didn't try anything else because this is the first time I used an `UPDATE` statement and it didn't work.

I have googled the error, most of which were regarding Insert statements and does not match with what I'm currently experiencing.

I asked ChatGPT, double checked column names, data types and it's accurate (which I have not changed so that wouldn't be an issue anyways)

I only did a little rollback to test when did the error occur and found out it occurs after the 2 new fields were added. Still, very strange.

I just want this Update statement to work or any alternatives that I can use for this.

It's quite confusing to me as this has never occurred to me before, especially with an `UPDATE` statement.

Hopefully someone can help on this. Thanks!

PS: let me know if there is any more information I need to provide, I cannot paste the codes here as my laptop is a standalone from work and cannot be plugged to any network.

Comment: Sounds like you have a badly written `TRIGGER` on your table that doesn't define the destination columns or uses a `SELECT *` (or worse, **both**!).

Comment: i would double check the column Names and even the dataType of the columns ID and LAST_UPDATED_DT

Comment: This error can only come from a failing insert, so look for places where insert is executed in your update statement. It's either trigger as @ThomA write, or perhaps you can have OUTPUT clause in your update which you forgot to include.

Comment: What do you see if you run `select * from sys.triggers where parent_id = Object_Id('dbo.claims')`

Comment: Hi All, thank you so much. I managed to find the trigger that does the Insert statement. The system was not designed by me and sometimes I just break my head trying to figure out what my predecessors did and why they did it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to read into the question and assume you either have a

1. trigger
2. view
3. some other code in the body where this is located

This happens to me all the time when I make a table variable or a temp table and the use an asterisk in the select statement instead of explicitly listing the columns I want.  In my case, the asterisk is pulling those two new columns but my temp table or variable table doesn't have them.

Look for stored procedures, triggers, anything with parameterized values that lead to an insert.

Comment: More of a long comment than an answer.